# Joomla 1.7 - Route to custom component

Tags: php, components, custom-component, joomla1.7

I have created a custom component in joomla 1.7 "com_custom_component". How to route to this component?

in joomla 1.5 it's something like, "index.php?option=com_custom_component&view=***"

How csn I achieve this in Joomla 1.7?

Answer (score 1):

It is same in Joomla 1.7

```
index.php?option=com_custom_component&view=custom_view
```